# Configuring Sharepoint Office Web Apps 2013

Tags: 2013

Im working on setting up a Production environment for sharepoint 2013
i have dedicated one server for Office Web Apps.
I succeeded installing office web apps with a powershell script.. But now I want to configure Office web apps through powershell... note - **Sharepoint is not installed in this server**

Is this possible ?? and HOW?

Answer (score 1):

If your Office Web APps installation is already done, you "just" need to configure SHarePoint 2013 to use the Web App Farm. There is a pretty good article on Technet about this (as most of the times these days):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687.aspx

As you are in production you will need/want to run on HTTPS. The command is as simple as this:

```
New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName <WacServerName>
#<WacServerName> is just the url without the schema for example; wac.mycompany.local and not https://wac.mycompany.local
```

Check out this document for additional configuration scenarios if you not already used it for your WAC setup:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219455.aspx